# How to run the following SMT-LIB code using Alt-Ergo

Tags: z3, cvc4, alt-ergo

The following SMT-LIB code runs without problems in Z3, MathSat and CVC4 but it is not running in Alt-Ergo, please let me know what happens, many thanks:

```
(set-logic QF_LIA)
(set-option :interactive-mode true) 
(set-option :incremental true)
(declare-fun w () Int)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(declare-fun z () Int)
(assert (> x y))
(assert (> y z))
(push 1)
(assert (> z x))
(check-sat)
(pop 1)
(get-info :all-statistics)
(push 1)
(assert (= x w))
(check-sat)
(get-assertions)
(exit)
```

Run this example online  [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/OqSE)

1. In Z3, the message `unsupported ; :incremental` is generated but this does not alter the computations and the correct answer is obtained.
2. In mathsat, some messages `unsupported`are generated but the correct answer is displayed.
3. In Cvc4  the code is executed without problems and the correct answer is obtained.
4. In Alt-Ergo the code is executed without messages but wrong answer `unsat` is generated ( the correct answer is : `unsat, sat`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute the following SMT-LIB code using Alt-Ergo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874099/how-to-execute-the-following-smt-lib-code-using-alt-ergo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Alt-Ergo and SMT-LIB2, please consider reading the answer to one of your previous posts here: [How to execute the following SMT-LIB code using Alt-Ergo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874099/how-to-execute-the-following-smt-lib-code-using-alt-ergo)

Comment: Thank you, now I understand why alt-ergo fails in this example.